# typescript type error cannot assign string or undefined to string[]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can't fix a typescript error, I check the console log and the regions that Set returns is an array of strings which is exactly what I have for region type in my state. Why would this not work?

Code:

```
const [regions, setRegions] = useState<string[]>([])

useEffect(() => {
    if (areasOptions) {
      const regions = [[...new Set(areasOptions.areas.map((item: ListObject) => item.region))]]
      setRegions(regions) // Error
    }
  }, [areasOptions])
```

Error:

> Argument of type '(string | undefined)[][]' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'SetStateAction'. [0]   Type '(string |
>   undefined)[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. [0]     Type
>   '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: You have two brackets there

Answer (score 0):

This non-react example should work for you:

```js
function setRegions(abc: string[]) {

}
type ListObject = {
    region: string
}

const areasOptions: {areas: ListObject[]} = {
    areas: [
        {region: "a"},
        {region: "b"}
    ]
}

const regions = [...new Set(areasOptions.areas.map((item) => item.region))]
setRegions(regions)
```